# How to change default browser to open localhost in wampserver

Tags: windows-7, localhost, wamp

When I installed wampserver on my computer. I didn't have firefox or any browser installed. Because I also disabled Internet explorer. How do I manually set the default browser that opens up localhost or phpmyadmin from wampserver when you left click it

Answer (score 33, accepted):

To change the default browser for the tray icon:

- Open `C:\wamp` in Windows Explorer (or wherever you installed wampserver)
- Open `wampmanager.conf` in a text editor

  - Find the section `[main]`
  - Find the following line:

    ```
    navigator = "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\IEXPLORE.EXE"
    ```
  - Replace it with:

    ```
    navigator = “C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe”
    ```
- Save the the file
- Restart the tray icon

Answer (score 4):

Open your `wampmanager.conf` file in a text editor; it is usually in `C:/wamp/wampmanager.conf`.

Under the section `[main]`, you will find the key `navigator`. Change its value to the path of your browser. For example:

```
navigator = "C:/Program Files/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe"
```

Restart the wampserver tray icon.

Answer (score 1):

this may not be exactly what you want, but may work for you.
You can set the shortcut properties target, and define which browser to use. 
This vista example is using chrome, but you can target whichever browser you prefer, just point to the application exe.

```
 C:\Users\anyUser\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --app=http://localhost/default.htm
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution more appropriate I think:

In your main wamp locate the file named wampmanager.ini (seems to be named wampserver.ini on some installs).
If you want to change only the browser for localhost, search for the [Menu.Left] section, around line 277. Two lines in that section define the path to the browser for localhost and phpmyadmin. Change it to point to the desired browser.

If you want to change every settings involving the preset browser, run a find command in the file with the browser's name.

Comment: That's for the old version. See [this forum post](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,13966).

Answer (score 0):

you can change in PHP user interface as:

Tools --> Preferences --> Browsers --> (locate the path of chrome.exe by clicking ... against chrome option i.e. C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe  and click OK.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using wampserver 64 open the file below with notpad:

```
C:\wamp64\wampmanager.ini
```

Search and replaces all files to your browser, for example:

```
C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\IEXPLORE.EXE
```

Replace it by your current browser, for example:

```
C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe
```

Save the file and restart the wampserver.

PS. [Join our affiliate platform features and earn income online.](http://www.sponsor-product.com/index.php?lang=en&page=index)